# DNS Wordpress moved from GoDaddy to OpenShift

Tags: wordpress, dns, openshift

I've moved my WordPress site from GoDaddy to OpenShift. All was working just fine with: dixons-visualwebfoundry.rhcloud.com

However I need to point the DNS across. I did as follows:

- Placed a forward on the DNS for dixons.net to dixons-visualwebfoundry.rhcloud.com
- Updated the CName for www to dixons-visualwebfoundry.rhcloud.com

It looks like it is forwarding

In WP, I used phpMyAdmin to change the two URLs to http://dixons.net

No when I go to dixons.net, I get the new page but without the formatting (I suspect the links need to be updated) but if I try to get to dixons.net/wp-admin , I get a browser error and dixons.net/wp-login-php just times out.

Comment: oh and yes of course I did add the alias in openshift

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to create a cname instead of using a forward.
You want to have a CNAME that points dixons.net to dixons-visualwebfoundry.rhcloud.com for everything to work properly.  Try reading through this section on the Developer Portal: https://developers.openshift.com/en/managing-domains-ssl.html

Comment: Thanks Corey. yes! You are absolutely right! Following your lead, WP doesn't seem to respect the Forward however with the CName (I placed the 'www' to the OpenShift URL) then changed the WP site names to http://www.dixons.net and suddenly now the WP permalink are being honored. So, I guess since my goal is for the naked domain name, I need to figure that our. Thanks for the help!!

Comment: I checked with GoDaddy, seems I have to use a CName. To use the naked domain means I need an IP Address. Given the shared nature of OpenShift obviously this isn't an topic. Does anyone know a provider who can enable my naked domain to point to OpenShift without the use of Forwarding?

Comment: You can create a name using the www.example.com, and then forward your naked domain to the www.example.com.  I have done that in the past and it works correctly.

Comment: That's basically what I've done Corey and yes that works but then I end up with the 'www' in the end result which is what I was trying to avoid.